# Changing permissions to allow PHP to list a folder from user directory

Tags: php, directory, chmod, permissions

I have a VPS with Debian and I want to make some kind of download site on it for people with SSH accounts. My problem is that i want to make a script in PHP which will list all files recursively from specyfic directory in users home folders. The script was easy to write but now I have problem with permissions. For example the folder is */home/someuser/resources* and it contains:

```
-file.txt      [file]
-info.doc      [file]
-data          [dir]
---numbers.xls [file]
---people.txt  [file]
-mail.doc      [file]
```

Unfortunately after listing this directory using PHP and absolute path I get

```
-file.txt      [file]
-info.doc      [file]
-data          [file] <- ?
-mail.doc      [file]
```

Yes. is_dir('/home/someuser/resources/data') return false. As i read in internet the problem is with permission. I changed in /etc/php5/cgi/php.inisafe_mode_gid to Off but it didn't help. I think that i need to change chmods. But how to make it work for sure? Can you help me with this?

Script which I use:
http://pastie.org/private/vxnhpkkisintjmncinqzw (it's a changed script from PHP manual comments)

Comment: Try chaning the directory permission with: chmod 755 data

Comment: Appears to be a code issue, not a server issue.

Answer (score 1):

Line 8: semantic: `while (false !== ...)` make that `while (...)`.

From reading your code, it appears that you're doing a fine job of reading the directory out, but that you're not parsing the nested arrays that show its contents. Thus, while files are read and stored, they're not printed out.

Comment: It's not a script fault because when i do getFilesFromDir('.') then i get a full list of all Wordpress files (this script is a part of Wordpress plugin). But thanks for try.